# Member function pointer in C++ for_each

Tags: c++, foreach, member-functions

I'm developing a small Virtual Machine in C++ for a school project, which should work like dc command, and is composed of a Input Output element, a Chipset, a Cpu and Ram. I'm currently working on the chipset, in which I've implemented a little parsing class in order to be able to get some Asm instructions from standard input or file, and then push this instructions to the Cpu.

The problem is: my instructions are sorted in a std::list, and I'd like to be able to push them each by each with a foreach instruction. To do that I need to be able to call my member function "push_instruction" as the function pointer F of for_each; and I wasn't able to find the trick to do that...

Any ideas?
here's my code:

```
/*
** Function which will supervise
** the lexing and parsing of the input (whether it's std_input or a file descriptor)
** the memory pushing of operands and operators
** and will command the execution of instructions to the Cpu
*/
void                    Chipset::startExecution()
{
    /*
    ** My parsing 
    ** Instructions
    **
    */

    for_each(this->_instructList.begin(), this->_instructList.end(), this->pushInstruction);
}


void                    Chipset::pushInstruction(instructionList* instruction)
{
    if (instruction->opCode == PUSH)
      this->_processor->pushOperand(instruction->value, Memory::OPERAND, Memory::BACK);
    else if (instruction->opCode == ASSERT)
      this->_processor->pushOperand(instruction->value, Memory::ASSERT, Memory::BACK);
    else
      this->_processor->pushOperation(instruction->opCode);
}
```

Comment: don't use underscores for your own identifiers.  The underscore is reserved for the compiler/stl implementation.

Comment: @xtofl: Aren't only identifiers with underscores _and_ a capital letter right after that reserved?

Comment: @ltjax: and leading underscores in namespace scope. And double underscore, leading or otherwise. It's just easier to avoid leading underscores in general, rather than keeping track of exactly when you can get away with using them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
std::for_each(
    _instructList.begin(), 
    _instructList.end(), 
    std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&Chipset::pushInstruction), this));
```

Comment: Exactly what I need, thank you very much!
But I'm not sure I deeply understand that. Shortly: it's telling G++ to make a functor of my member function (function considered as an object) and automaticaly overriding operator() of my Chipset class?

Comment: mem_fun creates a functor from a function pointer, the operator() expects a pointer to the correct object type as first argument. bind1st then creates a functor which binds the passed "this" to the first argument. So for_each calls the bind1st functor passing an instructionList *, then this functor calls the mem_fun functor passing your "this" and then instructionList *.

Answer (score 3):

When you can't remember the syntax for the `std::bind` functions, it is sometimes easier to write a functor which just forwards to the member function:

```
struct PushInstruction {
  PushInstruction(Chipset& self) : self(self) {} 

  void operator()(instructionList* instruction) {
    self.pushInstruction(instruction);
  }    

  Chipset& self;    
};

std::for_each(_instructList.begin(), _instructList.end(), PushInstruction(*this));
```

A bit of explanation:

I define a class which, in its constructor, takes the object we want to call `pushInstruction` on, and which stores a reference to the object.

Then I define an `operator()` hich takes the instruction you wish to push, and calls `pushInstruction`.

In the `for_each` loop, I just pass `this` to my constructor, creating an instance of the functor, which is passed to `for_each`, which then calls `operator()` on it for each element.

Comment: Very elegant solution I guess, but I'm not sure to completly understand that, I haven't used the "self" keyword yet...

Comment: self isn't a keyword, it's just a variable name. And this solution is a lot prettier than the IMO rather ugly bind*/mem_fun construct.

Comment: Oh okay, I've been misoriented by the Java/Php/Python "self" keyword then. Why is it a better solution? Performance? Complexity? Elegance?

Comment: @oleiade: `self` isn't a keyword, it's just a variable name. I use it precisely because of its Python meaning. It represents the current object, on which we wish to call  `pushInstruction`, so I feel `self` is a nice descriptive name. but there's nothing magic in it at all.

Comment: I doubt there's a difference in terms of performance. I prefer this solution because it's easier to remember. With the alternative, I have to remember how to use both `bind1st` and `mem_fun`, as well as the syntax for member pointers, so there's just a lot of scope for getting things wrong. A functor, on the other hand, is something I write all the time, and there is absolutely no special syntax to remmeber. Just define a class whose `operator()` calls the member function.

Comment: @oleiade: I added a bit of explanation in my post. Hope it helps.

Comment: @jalf: It does for sure! Thank you for your help, I've made it your way, as I realised I wouldn't have been capable of explain how bind1st would work if I was asked to; as I would be able to explain how operator() overriding does ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use `boost::bind` as,

```
std::for_each(/*..*/, /*..*/,
            boost::bind(&Chipset::pushInstruction, this, _1));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we're not allowed to use the Boost Library, but thank you, I'll keep this one in mind!

Comment: bind is also available as part of Technical Report 1 (as std::tr1::bind).

Answer (score 2):

You can `bind1st` your `this` pointer to obtain a functor applied on your cpu:

```
std::foreach( instructList.begin(), instructList.end(),
      std::bind1st
          ( std::mem_fun( &CChipSet::pushInstruction )
          , this 
          )
      );
```

(Note: I deliberately left away the underscore from your `_instructionList`.  It's not allowed.)

Comment: It is permitted, as long as it's not in the global namespace. "Each name that ... begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved to the implementation for any use. ... Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace." (17.4.3.1.2/1)

Comment: I totally agree with you though, just don't start with underscore and you don't have to remember the obscure underscore rules.

Comment: Thank you guys anyway for your answers :) Seems to make it