# Having a function inside for_each statement

Tags: c++

I keep on getting error message while trying to pass a function inside a for_each loop.. I have a vector and i used for_each loop to go through the rows in that vector, Now I need a function to do something

Example this is what I am trying to achieve:

```
void DataPartitioning::doSomething()
{
    for_each (label.begin(), label.end(), addToTemporaryVector());
}

void DataPartitioning::addToTemporaryVector()
{
    cout<<"sucess";
}
```

But I get an error message saying: error: invalid use of void expression both of them are in same class.

Comment: You need to pass a function, not the result of calling one. But note that passing a member function is tricky because it needs an object to act on.

Comment: so do you mean, I should create a structure and include the function inside it?

Comment: @George You should do it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050494/member-function-pointer-in-c-for-each

Comment: @George: Or use a lambda, or `std::bind`, or a regular for-loop.

Comment: If your compiler supports it, [check out the range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: The purpose of for_each is to run a function that takes an iterated item as an argument. Why do you want to use for_each if the value of each label is not used?

Comment: Also, in your example, the addToTemporaryVector function does not use `this`. So it could be static, and you would have no problem passing it to for_each then

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a member function, you'll need to wrap it in a functor that calls it on an object; presumably the same object that `doSomething` was called on:

```
for_each(label.begin(), label.end(), [this](whatever const &){addToTemporaryVector();});
```

where `whatever` is the value type of the container.

It might be clearer as a regular for-loop:

```
for (whatever const & thing : label) {
    addToTemporaryVector();
}
```

This assumes you're not stuck with a pre-C++11 compiler. If you are, it requires rather more gibberish:

```
for_each(label.begin(), label.end(),
    std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&DataPartitioning::addToTemporaryVector), this));
```

I'm not entirely sure whether that will work with a function like yours that doesn't take an argument; but presumably your real code does take an argument to do something with each element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a struct as here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Operation
{
    void operator()(string n) { cout<<"success"<<endl; }
};

int main() {
    vector<string> vInts(10,"abc");
  std::for_each(std::begin(vInts), std::end(vInts), Operation());   
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the input of the operator has to be the same as the type in the vector. (string in this example, int in the link)

Answer (score 0):

The `addToTemporaryVector` function does not use `this`. So you can declare it as static.

Also, it should take as argument the template type of `label`

Declaration:

```
static void addToTemporaryVector(const SomeType & item);
```

Then just do:

```
//No parentheses to the function pointer
for_each (label.begin(), label.end(), addToTemporaryVector);
```